# How to aggregate results from SELECT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate

I have two tables:

**user Table **

```
id   username
---  -----------
100  greg
101  john
102  patrick
103  bill
```

**user_subscription_plan Table **

```
id   user_id     amount
---  ---------   -------
1   100           50
2   100           52
3   101           10
4   103           100
5   103           110
```

I would like to make a query on the user table to extract username, but also to include id's from USER_SUBSCRIPTION which are related to the user_id

This is what I was trying:

```
SELECT
   u.id AS user_id,
   u.username AS username,
   usp.id AS subscription_id
   FROM user AS u
INNER JOIN user_subscription_plan usp on usp.id = u.id;
```

It gets me the results, but not in the form I need. If the user has two subscription entries, then it returns two rows for each subscription.

I would need to get only ids from Subscription table. Something like this:

```
SELECT
   u.id AS user_id,
   u.username AS username,
   usp.id AS subscription_ids -- Array of ids for each user
   FROM user AS u
INNER JOIN user_subscription_plan usp on usp.id = u.id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
SELECT
   u.id AS user_id,
   u.username AS username,
   GROUP_CONCAT(usp.id) AS subscription_ids -- Array of ids for each user
   FROM user AS u
INNER JOIN user_subscription_plan usp on usp.id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id,u.username;
```

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php#SP